# Where does the number "74" belong?

Tags: assembly

I have written something in assembly, and after that I try to look at it using objdump. Then I see the following:

```
 .....
 8048082:     70 2f                jo   80480b3 <GoToCall2+0x23>
 8048084:    66 69 6c 65 74 78     imul bp, WORD PTR [ebp+eiz*2+0x2e]
74
 804808b:    74 5c                 je   80480e9 <GoToCall2+0x59>
 .... (and so on)
```

So, as you can see:
In the middle we have the number "74" and I ask myself where it does belong? Is it a part of the opcodes? Or belongs it to the assembly column of line 8048084 ? 
I make the size of the screen a little bigger but it was still there,
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What's your input assembly?

Comment: Why not print the machine code in wide format so there are no line breaks?

Answer (score 2):

It belongs here:

```
8048084: 66 69 6c 65 74 78 74  imul...
                           ^^
804808b: ...
```

Look at the addresses in the left column: they are seven bytes apart.